# The package knitr without using Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

As a beginner I do not know whether I can use the package knitr without using Rstudio and only with using open-source R (not with a special graphical user interface for R) or with using Revolution R enterprise?

I have not found any example or tutorial to use knitr in Revolution R enterprise or open-source R.

As far as I know, In Rstudio, I can create an R Sweave document and then compile Pdf for a document with Rnw extension but what should I do to make a Sweave document in Revolution R Enterprise or in open-source R.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I had to make a Sweave document in Rstudio (called Latex.Rnw) and run the following commands in Revolution R Enterprize since I could not find how to make a Sweave document in Revolution R Enterprize!

```
library(knitr)
Myfile = system.file("Latex","Latex.Rnw", package = "knitr")
knit(Myfile,output="C:/Users/shima/Documents/R/win-library/2.14/knitr/Latex/Latex.tex")
setwd("C:/Users/shima/Documents/R/win-library/2.14/knitr/Latex")
tools::texi2pdf("C:/Users/shima/Documents/R/win-library/2.14/knitr/Latex/Latex.tex")
```

It was a really tedious job to compile the document from  Revolution R Enterprize and I eventually gave it up.

Comment: Rstudio allows integrates knitr commands in its menu commands.

Answer (score 0):

knitr is a stand-alone R package that can be used with any version of R.  To install in any version of R, just type:

```
install.packages("knitr")
```

Documentation and demos can be found at http://yihui.name/knitr/